# count unique pair in graph (vertices repetition not allowed)

Tags: algorithm, graph

Is there any Algorithm exists for counting unique pair (pair of vertices) in `undirected graph` (vertices repetition not allowed). I think it could be a variation of bipartite graph but if there is any better way to find out .. please comment.
**[I think Problem Belongs to Perfect Matching Algorithm]**
**Problem Statement:**
`I have an undirected graph which consists of n vertexes and m edges. I can delete edges from the graph. Now I'm interested in one question : is it possible to delete edges in the graph so that the degree of each vertex in the graph will be equal 1.. There can be multiple edges in the graph, but can not be any loops`

Example: n = #vertices, m = #edges 
n = 4, m = 6
1 2
1 3
1 4
2 3
2 4
3 4
Unique sequence could be (1 2, 3 4) (1 4, 2 3) (1 3, 2 4)

Comment: are you counting pairs of non-connected edges ?

Comment: Yes ! If you see the example you'll get the clear idea.

Comment: Can you try to at least add some description about the "non-connected edges"? For your example alone, there are so many ways to understand (as your graph is a special case, which is a completed graph) and it will take a lot of time to interpret correctly. Try to be professional! Pair here means edges? or just connected nodes? I am so confused!

Comment: @Cereal_Killer Also, make it clear what is your question exactly ? You have 2 different and separate problems in your question (one for number of pairs of edges, another is for perfect matching). Check my answer for first. And Perfect matching is much tricker as *Heuster* explained in his answer.

Comment: You just completely changed your question. The new formulation has nothing to do with counting anymore, it just asks whether there exists a perfect matching.

Comment: You need to count because if (count == n/2) then only it will be perfect matching.

Comment: no, (count == n/2) is not sufficient condition. For example consider graph (1,2), (2,3), (3,4), n = 4, number of non-connected edges pairs = 1 : edges (1,2) and (3,4), and 1 != 4/2, but perfect matching exists.

Comment: @kiruwka If you delete edge 2-3 then there are 4 vertices having indegree 1 and number of Edges are 2 it has to be count = n/2 <PS: I'm counting connected Edge>

Answer (score 1):

The set of edges that covers the entire graph without using the same vertex multiple times is called a **matching** or **independent edge set**, see [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_%28graph_theory%29).

In that article is also mentioned that the number of distinct matchings in a graph (which is the number you are after) is called the **Hosoya index**, see [this wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosoya_index).

Algorithms to compute this number are not trivial and Stack Overflow wouldn't be the right place to try to explain them, but I at least I hope you have enough pointers to investigate further.

Answer (score 1):

Here is pseudo code, it should run in `O(|E|)` time, i.e. linear of number of edges :

Suppose `G = (V, E)` is your initial graph, with `E` - initial set of all edges

```
count = 0;
while(E is not empty) {
    //1. pick up any edge e = (n1, n2) from E

    //2. remove e from G
    E = E - e;

    //3. calculate number of edges in G remaining if nodes n1 and n2 were removed
    // -> these are edges making pair with e
    edges_not_connected_to_e = |E| - |n1| - |n2|;
    // where |n1| - degree of n1 in updated G (already without edge e)

    //4. update the count
    count += edges_not_connected_to_e;
}
return count;
```

Let me know if you need more clarifications. And probably someone could fix my Graph math notations, in case they are incorrect.

Comment: @sp1rs sure. So, we start with original graph. Then we iteratively remove one edge each time. After we removed that edge e = (n1,n2), we calculate how many edges in remaining graph are not adjacent to e, i.e. how many edges do not have n1 nor n2 as vertex : |E| - |n1| - |n2|, and then we update the count. We remove e because we already counted all pairs containing e. I suggest you try the algorithm on a simple graph, such as one in the question and let me know if you still have troubles understanding

Comment: what value of count determine ?

Comment: the value asked in OP question : number of pairs of non-connected edges